# python matching list items

Tags: python, string, parsing, dictionary

I'm using python 2.6
current output

```
mylist = [('log:A', '1009.2'), ('log:B', '938.1'), ('log:C', '925.7'), ('log:C', '925.7')]
```

I'am trying to add the values to produce the follow:
Ranked highest to lowest.
The problem I'am having is adding everthing with a log:C tag together.
and not outputting it twice.

```
log:C = 1851.4
log:A = 1009.2
log:B = 938.1
```

Comment: why did you change the input? There are 3 answers below based on your previous input.

Comment: I realised the the final output the file was giving me was in a list.

Comment: Then how does the accepted answer solves your new input?

Comment: It doesn't but they spent the time doing the code and I didn't want to waste their time. do you have a way I could fix it?

Comment: I've added solutions for both of your inputs , what else do you want?http://stackoverflow.com/a/16848422/846892

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `collections.defaultdict`:

```
>>> strs = "log:A 22 log:B 44 log:C 74 log:D 24 log:B 10"
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> dic = defaultdict(int)
>>> it = iter(strs.split())
>>> for k in it:
...     dic[k] += int(next(it)) 
...     
>>> for k,v in sorted(dic.items(), key = lambda x: x[1], reverse = True):
...     print k,v
...     
log:C 74
log:B 54
log:D 24
log:A 22
```

To get a sorted list of items based on values:

```
>>> sorted(dic.items(), key = lambda x: x[1], reverse = True)
[('log:C', 74), ('log:B', 54), ('log:D', 24), ('log:A', 22)]
```

**Update:** Based on your new input

```
>>> mylist = [('log:A', '1009.2'), ('log:B', '938.1'), ('log:C', '925.7'), ('log:C', '925.7')]
>>> dic = defaultdict(int)
>>> for k,v in mylist:                                                                        
       dic[k] += float(v)
...     
>>> sorted(dic.items(), key = lambda x: x[1], reverse = True)
[('log:C', 1851.4), ('log:A', 1009.2), ('log:B', 938.1)]
```

Comment: @user2371027 I've updated my solution based on you new input.

Comment: you're such a boss @Ashwini Chaudhary  now i can check all the stats of my online hockey game just by searching the two alias. soon the top 10 will be working also thanks to you! :) http:www.thetutoria.com/cgi-bin/statistics.py  if you want to check it out.

Answer (score 2):

```
mystr = 'log:A 22 log:B 44 log:C 74 log:D 24 log:B 10'

li=mystr.split()

res={}
for k,v in zip(li[::2],li[1::2]):
    res.setdefault(k,[]).append(int(v))

print res
```

Prints:

```
{'log:D': [24], 'log:A': [22], 'log:C': [74], 'log:B': [44, 10]}
```

Then just sum them:

```
for k in sorted(res):
   print k, sum(res[k])
```

Prints:

```
log:A 22
log:B 54
log:C 74
log:D 24
```

Comment: Actually, `sum(['44', '10'])` will give you this: `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'`. This solution won't work unless you will first do mapping to floats (not integers, see the question). But generally is okay.

Comment: @Tadeck: Version control... Fixed. Thx

Answer (score 0):

```
import collections
import operator

mystr = "log:A 22 log:B 44 log:C 74 log:D 24 log:B 10"
s = mystr.split()
d = collections.defaultdict(int)
for i in xrange(0, len(s), 2):
    d[s[i]] += int(s[i+1])
# alternate way:
# i = iter(s)
# for k, v in itertools.izip(i, i):
#     d[k] += int(v)
result = sorted(d.iteritems(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
# [('log:C', 74), ('log:B', 54), ('log:D', 24), ('log:A', 22)]
```